# Indexing Between two Matrices

Tags: matlab, indexing, point

I have two Matrices (V; Vertex Node Coordinates x,y,z & T; List of Triangles showing the nodes (1,2,3) that make up the triangle)

I want to replace the values in T with the coordinates of the corresponding vertex nodes ie:

```
V
    1 --- 1.35234 1.2542445 1.32234324
    2 --- 3.42354 1.2521345 1.34325524
    3 --- 2.26434 1.2323345 1.33225324
T
1 2 3 

should go to 

T_V

1.35234 1.2542445 1.32234324 3.42354 1.2521345 1.34325524 2.26434 1.2323345 1.33225324
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you saying you have a matrix V and want to make it into a single line vector T?

Comment: no what i want to do is connect the two Matrices i have (V and T), to clarify i want the vertex Points in T to connect to V and pull the coordinates from V

Comment: By connect do you mean that T specifies what order to pull the triangle's nodes out of V?

Comment: well no not really, T has all the participating nodes of a triangle, its a list of all triangles in my mesh. so for example triangle 1 -- 1,2,3 ; triangle 2 -- 2,3,4 ; triangle 3 -- 3,4,5 , those are the vertex Points and the vertex martix contains the coordinates of those Points, and for each participating node in T i want to have the corresponding coordinates of that specific node

Comment: @AlanDeMoin consider reading [ask], and what a [mcve] is, to improve future questions ;)

Answer (score 1):

It `T` is always a `(1x3)` array you can try:

```
T_V=reshape(V(T(:),:)',1,numel(T)*size(V,2))
```

For a more general case, in case `T` is a matrix such as, for exampale:

```
T=[1 2 3;4 5 6]
```

for  a `V` matrix such as

```
V=[
1.35234 1.2542445 1.32234324
3.42354 1.2521345 1.34325524
2.26434 1.2323345 1.33225324
10 20 30
40 50 60
70 80 90]
```

you can try:

```
T1=T'
V_T=reshape(V(T1(:),:)',1,numel(T1)*size(V,2))
```

**Edit**

In case the expected shape of the `T_V` matrix is `(n_row of T x 9)` you can try (I've added some rows on both `V` and `T` for test purpose):

```
V=[
1.35234 1.2542445 1.32234324
3.42354 1.2521345 1.34325524
2.26434 1.2323345 1.33225324
10 20 30
40 50 60
70 80 90]

T=[1 2 3
5 4 6]

T1=T'

T_V=reshape(reshape(V(T1(:),:)',1,numel(T1)*3),size(T,2)*size(V,2),size(T))'
```

The resulting `T_V` matrix:

```
T_V =

    1.3523    1.2542    1.3223    3.4235    1.2521    1.3433    2.2643    1.2323    1.3323
   40.0000   50.0000   60.0000   10.0000   20.0000   30.0000   70.0000   80.0000   90.0000
```

*Notice: tested with Octave*

Comment: Well my T Matrix is a x by 3 and V is also an x by 3 (2000 and 1300 respectively), is there a way to Keep the shape of the Matrix instead of forming a 1x3 ?

Comment: your edit bounces and error if executed : Size arguments must be integer scalars.

Comment: As written in the answer, I've tested the code with `Octave` and it works, I can not tell if the error you've got depend on the diferences between `MatLab` and `OCtave`. I've updated the code in the answer by posting the whole code and the results.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you mean something this basic, but

```
V = [1.35234 1.2542445 1.32234324;
      3.42354 1.2521345 1.34325524;
      2.26434 1.2323345 1.33225324];
T = [1 2 3]
Tv = [V(T(1),:),V(T(1),:),V(T(3),:)];
```

Comment: Tv = [V(T(1),:),V(T(1),:),V(T(3),:)]; this works, but its only for one triangle, and id like to have it as length of T

Comment: got it now ! thank you very much had to add Tv= [V(T(:,1),:),T(F(:,2),:),V(T(:,3),:)];

Comment: @AlanDeMoin Consider updating and accepting the answer that worked